# Is there a way to combine the results of queries on two unrelated tables

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

**A quick question:**

I have results from two SQL Queries,

The first one queries for a column named as `svb_rate` for the `CURRENT_DATE` from a particular table named as `ODS.PS_RT_RATE_TBL`

The second one queries for a column named as `PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET` from another table named as `FRDS_LOANS_MV`

My aim is to multiply these two columns and get the results in a new column.

The main problem is that the two tables mentioned above are unrelated, hence we will not be able to execute joins, to my knowledge.

I considered using cross joins, but I am not sure it would work.

Is there a way to get the required answer, or is it not possible.

Please do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: Cross join would work, but the question is what will result look like. You know how it goes - garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Second @Mureinik, without any context it's hard to help. Though I would go out on a limb and suggest there is possibly a relationship (e.g. date). Could you describe the data in more detail, and what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik I am afraid that the data is proprietary (security reasons). Neither can I share the schema

Comment: That's then great news for us (we don't have to do anything as we can't do anything) and pretty bad news for you (as you won't get any assistance).

Answer (score 0):

Just a few thoughts about your question. Without sample data it is impossible to give an answer. So, if we put that sample data like below (just for testing):

PS_RT_RATE_TBL

| A_DATE | SVB_RATE |
| --- | --- |
| 27-DEC-22 | 2.5 |
| 28-DEC-22 | 1.75 |
| 29-DEC-22 | 1.5 |
| 30-DEC-22 | 1.38 |
| 31-DEC-22 | 1.3 |

FRDS_LOANS_MV

| LOAN_ID | PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 999.45 |
| 2 | 998.83 |
| 3 | 998.15 |

**1. CROSS JOIN**
If there is a table with 5 rows and another with 3 rows we will get 15 rows as a resulting dataset

```sql
Select      r.A_DATE, r.SVB_RATE, l.PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET, l.LOAN_ID
From        PS_RT_RATE_TBL r
Cross Join  FRDS_LOANS_MV l
Order By    l.LOAN_ID, r.A_DATE
```

Doesn't look very usefull - not knowing what you need, though

| A_DATE | SVB_RATE | PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET | LOAN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27-DEC-22 | 2.5 | 999.45 | 1 |
| 28-DEC-22 | 1.75 | 999.45 | 1 |
| 29-DEC-22 | 1.5 | 999.45 | 1 |
| 30-DEC-22 | 1.38 | 999.45 | 1 |
| 31-DEC-22 | 1.3 | 999.45 | 1 |
| 27-DEC-22 | 2.5 | 998.83 | 2 |
| 28-DEC-22 | 1.75 | 998.83 | 2 |
| 29-DEC-22 | 1.5 | 998.83 | 2 |
| 30-DEC-22 | 1.38 | 998.83 | 2 |
| 31-DEC-22 | 1.3 | 998.83 | 2 |
| 27-DEC-22 | 2.5 | 998.15 | 3 |
| 28-DEC-22 | 1.75 | 998.15 | 3 |
| 29-DEC-22 | 1.5 | 998.15 | 3 |
| 30-DEC-22 | 1.38 | 998.15 | 3 |
| 31-DEC-22 | 1.3 | 998.15 | 3 |

**2. PIVOT**
The above cross joined data could be pivoted

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM      ( Select      r.A_DATE, r.SVB_RATE, l.PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET, l.LOAN_ID
            From        PS_RT_RATE_TBL r
            Cross Join  FRDS_LOANS_MV l
            Order By    l.LOAN_ID, r.A_DATE
          )
    PIVOT (
              Count(A_DATE) "DAYS", Avg(SVB_RATE) "AVG_RATE", Min(PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET) "BAL_NET"
              For LOAN_ID In(1 "ID_1", 2 "ID_2", 3 "ID_3")
          )
```

Still looks odd and not saying much...

| ID_1_DAYS | ID_1_AVG_RATE | ID_1_BAL_NET | ID_2_DAYS | ID_2_AVG_RATE | ID_2_BAL_NET | ID_3_DAYS | ID_3_AVG_RATE | ID_3_BAL_NET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1.686 | 999.45 | 5 | 1.686 | 998.83 | 5 | 1.686 | 998.15 |

**3. UNPIVOT**

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM
        (SELECT    *
         FROM      (Select      r.A_DATE, r.SVB_RATE, l.PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET, l.LOAN_ID
                    From        PS_RT_RATE_TBL r
                    Cross Join  FRDS_LOANS_MV l
                    Order By    l.LOAN_ID, r.A_DATE
                  )
                PIVOT (
                          Count(A_DATE) "DAYS", Avg(SVB_RATE) "AVG_RATE", Min(PRINCIPAL_BAL_NET) "BAL_NET"
                          For LOAN_ID In(1 "ID_1", 2 "ID_2", 3 "ID_3")
                      )
        )
      UNPIVOT ( 
                  ( AVG_RATE, BAL_NET, DAYS)
                  For ID
                  IN( ( ID_1_AVG_RATE, ID_1_BAL_NET, ID_1_DAYS) As 1, 
                      ( ID_2_AVG_RATE, ID_2_BAL_NET, ID_2_DAYS) As 2,
                      ( ID_3_AVG_RATE, ID_3_BAL_NET, ID_3_DAYS) As 3
                    )
              )
```

Well, even if it doesn't help - it looks nicer now...

| ID | AVG_RATE | BAL_NET | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.686 | 999.45 | 5 |
| 2 | 1.686 | 998.83 | 5 |
| 3 | 1.686 | 998.15 | 5 |

You can do your own pivoting and unpivoting - this is just to give you some options to think about and, as such, just an example on imaginary sample data.
***NOTE: You can do multiplication of your columns in any of above 3 steps.***